# Need a regular expression in C# to do the following listed below

Tags: regex

can anyone help me with coming up with regular expression o find the following in C#
[39,UNBUN_PAIRS] has bad exclusion indicator type [ S].

I want to ensure that we are finding [NUM, LETTER]  AND ENDING WITH TYPE[# OR LETTER].

Can anyone give me a c# code that will do this?

Comment: You could google regular expressions in c#. There are only 2.2 million hits.

Comment: Hmm *Unbun Pairs* - Looks like one of those CAPTCHAs you have to type in..

Comment: Thank you, just to clarify, I basically wanted the regular expression that will capture "["  a number or int "1" a comma "," and Any Letter" PAY_PERCENT   hence [35,PAY_PERCENT_PROC]  i am parsing a log and just wanted some help with the regular expression ... thanks

Answer (score 1):

So like:

```
\[\d+\,[A-Z_]+\]
```

Matches [, then one or more numbers, then a comma, then one or more capital letters or underscores, then the ending ].

Comment: YESS! AWESOME GUYS THANK YOU !!!!!string Pattern = @"\[\d+\,[A-Z_]+\]";

Code is like this   if (Regex.IsMatch(line, Pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
                {
                    richTextBox1.AppendText(line + "\n");
                }

Comment: How would i go about searching for the following? 11/11/2011 9:40:08 AM :  bascially find date within a file

Comment: @KhemlallMangal if you found Mike's answer helpful, then upvote it.  If it's the answer, mark it as the answer, and if you have another question, ask it as another question, don't ask it in a comment...

Comment: @KhemlallMangal - These are very simple RegEx patterns.. perhaps you should read up a bit on the basics before posting any more?  I'm partial to Wikipedia's article on the subject: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regex

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what your data looks like, but I use [this](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx) all the time for testing or trying to create regular expressions for .net.  Give it a try!

Comment: hank you, just to clarify, I basically wanted the regular expression that will capture "[" a number or int "1" a comma "," and Any Letter" PAY_PERCENT hence [35,PAY_PERCENT_PROC] i am parsing a log and just wanted some help with the regular expression ... thanks